# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3000/users' from origin 'http://localhost:62521' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: node.js, flutter, rest, dart, cors

I am getting this error even though I have allowed CORS in my code. This one is in Node js:

```
app.use(cors());

app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    res.set({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST,GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS'
    });

    User.find({}, function(err, users){
        

        if(err)
        {
            return res.status(500).send({err});
        }
        return res.send(users);
    });
});
```

I am just trying to do a GET request from http://localhost:3000/users using Flutter:

```
import 'package:retrofit/http.dart' as head;

@head.RestApi(baseUrl: "http://localhost:3000")
abstract class ApiClient {
  factory ApiClient(Dio dio, {String baseUrl}) = _ApiClient;

  @head.GET("/users")
  Future<User> getUsers();
}
```

Doing this GET request works just fine in Postman but it doesn't work in Flutter because of the CORS. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: The error should tell you what header you are missing. It's probably the one ending in `-Origin`

Comment: I also tried that @Evert but to no avail. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only allowed Headers and Method, try adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and assigning it to `*` or website URLs.

```js
res.set({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST,GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Pyxl. I have tried also adding that but to no avail.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the mark, but since my answer didn't solve your problems I suggest you unmark my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Express?
Try this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
...
const cors = require("cors");
...
const corsOptions = {
  origin: ['http://localhost:62521'],
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers     (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions)); // CORS policy
```

Answer (score 0):

if u use node js ,
do this steps,
1- in ur terminal write `npm install cors`
2- in ur server.js write this

```
let cors = require("cors"); //use this
app.use(cors()); //and this
```